# Exponential Form Conversion

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Does   $(\sqrt[3]{3k})^4 = (3k)^{4/3}$ or $((3k)^{1/3})^4$?

I thought the first one is correct, but when I looked at it again I saw that $(3k)^{4/3} = \sqrt[3]{(3k)^4} $

Comment: All three forms are identical.

Comment: If it says in my instructions to put it in exponential form, which one should I write as my final answer?

Comment: I would _think_ the second one (since it's in the form of $(3k)^{\text{exponent }}$. But you might ask for clarification to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All forms are equivalent.

By definition

$\sqrt[3]{3k} = (3k)^{1/3}$

and the exponents multiply:

$((3k)^{1/3})^4 = (3k)^{1/3 \times 4} = (3k)^{4/3}$